# Add values of two nested for loops in a dataframe

Tags: python, excel, dataframe

I have a problem with two nested for loops, that in a simplified fashion would be something like this:

```
var1 = [1,2]
var2 = [10,20,30]

for i in var1:
     for j in var2:
```

I want to add those values in each iteration to create a table like this:

| Var1 | Var2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 20 |
| 1 | 30 |
| 2 | 10 |
| 2 | 20 |
| 2 | 30 |

I thought that the best approach would be to create a dataframe to convert to an excel file. However, I don't know how to create that dataframe and add the corresponding values in each iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put them both inside a dictionary and append the values inside the loop:

```
var1 = [1,2]
var2 = [10,20,30]
my_dict = {'var1':[],'var2':[]}
for i in var1:
  for j in var2:
    my_dict['var1'].append(i)
    my_dict['var2'].append(j)
df =pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can form 2d array containing values of var1 and var2 and pass it to the dataframe as below:

```
import pandas as pd

var1 = [1,2]
var2 = [10,20,30]

# for 2d array containing each value of var1/var2
data = [[i, j] for i in var1 for j in var2]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Var1', 'Var2'])
file_name = "data.xlsx"
df.to_excel(file_name)
```

Result would look like:

```
   Var1  Var2
0     1    10
1     1    20
2     1    30
3     2    10
4     2    20
5     2    30
```

You also need to install `openpyxl` using:

```
pip install openpyxl
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```py
    var1 = [1,2]
var2 = [10,20,30]
var3 = []
var4 = []
for i in var1:
    a = 0
    for j in var2:
        var4.append(var1[i - 1])
        var3.append(var2[a])
        a = a + 1


print(var4)
print(var3)
```

With that:
var3 = [10, 20, 30, 10, 20, 30]
and
var4 = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
This works with lists of any size.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
var1 = [1,2]
var2 = [10,20,30]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Var1', 'Var2'])
for i in var1:
    for j in var2:
        df = df.append({'Var1':i,'Var2':j},ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```